# Post data form submit with jquery mobile and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc

I'm having problems with submit a form data to a server. I'm using jquery mobile and Ajax to post data, and Spring Mvc to implement the controller. Until the moment i obtain this apache tomcat error:

Estado HTTP 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported

mensaje Request method 'GET' not supported

descripción El método HTTP especificado no está permitido para el recurso requerido.

This is mi Ajax call:

```
function enviarCita(){      

        var frm = $("#regCitaForm").serialize();

        alert(frm);

        $.ajax({            
            type: "POST",
            url:  url+ '/AgendaProfesional/solicitudCita',
            data: $('#regCitaForm').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",


            success: function(){
                $("loading").html("here i am"); 
                $.post(url+ '/AgendaProfesional/solicitudCita', data);
                }
        });
            return false;
            e.preventDefault();

        };
```

This is my html form to post:

```
<form  modelAttribute="Solicitud" method="POST" name="regCitaForm"  id="regCitaForm">
<input type="text"data-theme="a"  path="nombre_paciente" name="nume" id="nume" size="20" maxlength="33" placeholder="Nombre"/><br />
```

.....

(It has more inputs...)

and this is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/solicitudCita", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String putSolicitud(@RequestBody  Solicitud solicitudCitaAppM){



        System.out.println(solicitudCitaAppM.toString());

        solicitudCitaAppMService.createOrUpdate(solicitudCitaAppM);

        String solicitudAdded = "Solicitud de cita -> {" + solicitudCitaAppM.toString() + "} añadida";

        System.out.println(solicitudCitaAppM);

       return solicitudAdded;

    }
```

I dont know if I pass the correct atributes to json because the javascript console recognizes the post method but shows 405 error (GET not suported).

Please help me.

Thanks a lot¡

Comment: You do close the form tag right?

Comment: Yes, the html code just rigth. I think that maybe the columns at database table are not the same as the form inputs...

Comment: You have two postings for the same problem.  Having just looked at your Spring Controller code, I can tell you that your Controller is expecting a POST, and it looks like it's receiving a GET.  I would use something like Firebug or Google Chrome's dev tools to see what is being sent.  I would bet there is something wrong in your JavaScript and/or HTML code that is causing it to send a GET.

Comment: put the submit button outside of the form tag